# How to stop execution of a data retreieve until an other arrays fill with data

Tags: angular

Guys, I have a Datatable on angular and I wanna fill it with an object but first I need to modify the value of its data. The problem is the new data comes from another service, So first I need to retrieve department service data before going to retrieve and modify the Datatable data. Maybe a callback function can solve my problem but I don't know how to use it on angular.

My code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.id=this._Activatedroute.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.service.get_cars().subscribe((data)=>{// get departement service data
      console.log(data);
      this.UIGestionlist = json2array(data);
      this.departements = this.UIGestionlist[5];
      this.ChauffeursListe = this.UIGestionlist[6];

    });
    this.service.Car_log_charge(this.id).subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      this.Car_logs = json2array(data);
            for(let i= 0; i<this.Car_logs.length;i++){// modify Datatable departement value
        console.log(this.Car_logs[i].Department);
        for(let m =0 ; m<this.departements.length;m++){
          if(this.departements[m].Id == this.Car_logs[i].Department){
            console.log('Congs '+ this.departements[m].Id);
            this.Car_logs[i].Department = this.departements[m].Name;
          }
        }
      }

      this.listdata = new MatTableDataSource(this.Car_logs);
      this.listdata.sort = this.sort;
      this.listdata.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) `switchMap`.  This allows you to "chain" observables.  You can make your first call (`get_cars`), do your data manipulation, and then subscribe to your second call (`Car_log_change`).